# stm32 usart dma receive not starting if byte in data register

Tags: stm32, stm32f4

What are the requirements for enabling UART DMA receive on the STM32 series?  From my observation, if any stale data is in the uart receive data register, it will prevent the dma from starting when enabled (I believe because no new data will trigger the dma interrupt to clear that byte out and continue on as normal).

If in interrupt context and data is received after the dmar bit is set (i.e. uart dma receive enabled), will the dma clear out that bit once exiting the interrupt or will that lock up the dma?  if so, how to prevent this race condition between when dma is enabled and when exiting interrupt context (note all interrupts are same priority, so interrupts are effectively disabled while in the current interrupt).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

- After setting up DMA, clear the `RXNE` bit in `UARTx->SR`.

or

- Save `CR1`, set `CR1` to 0 (or clear the `RE` bit), read `SR` and `DR`, set up DMA, and restore `CR1`.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I end up doing, although my question is rather why won't the DMA automatically read out that byte? @berendi